# Why does compiling my project to dll give error codes C2664 and E0289 error when compiling?

Tags: c++, dll, compiler-errors, compilation, c2664

```
BOOL CALLBACK callback(HWND hwnd, LPARAM param) {
    DWORD pid;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
    if (pid == param) {
        TCHAR classNameBuf[MAX_PATH];
        GetClassName(hwnd, classNameBuf, MAX_PATH);
        std::string className(&classNameBuf[0]);
        if (className != ("MSCTFIME UI") && className != ("IME") && className != ("ConsoleWindowClass")) {
            window_handle = hwnd;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I try to compile my project and run it, it gives these errors.:

> Error E0289 no instance of constructor "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list

And this one

> Error C2664 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::basic_string(std::initializer_list<_Elem>,const _Alloc &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'TCHAR *' to 'std::initializer_list<_Elem>'

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like your project is configured to have `TCHAR` alias wide characters, not the common `char` that's acceptable to `std::string`. Try `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `TCHAR`-based `GetClassName()` macro, and you have your project set to define `UNICODE`, thus `TCHAR` is mapped to `wchar_t`, not `char`.  You can't create a `std::string` from a `wchar[]` array (well, not the way you are trying to, anyway).

So, either:

- change your project settings to use the MBCS charset instead of UNICODE, so that `TCHAR` maps to `char`, and `GetClassName` maps to `GetClassNameA()`.
- don't use `TCHAR` at all, use `GetClassNameA()` directly, eg:

  ```
  CHAR classNameBuf[MAX_PATH];
  GetClassNameA(hwnd, classNameBuf, MAX_PATH);
  std::string className(classNameBuf);
  if (className != "MSCTFIME UI" && ...)
  ```
- if you really want to use `TCHAR` (which you shouldn't - this is not the '90s), you can use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` instead, just be sure to wrap your string literals with the `TEXT()` macro, eg:

  ```
  TCHAR classNameBuf[MAX_PATH] = {};
  GetClassName(hwnd, classNameBuf, MAX_PATH);
  std::basic_string<TCHAR> className(classNameBuf);
  if (className != TEXT("MSCTFIME UI") && ...)
  ```
- you can just avoid `std::(basic_)string` altogether and use `lstrcmp()` instead to match the same `TCHAR` encoding that `GetClassName()` uses, eg:

  ```
  TCHAR classNameBuf[MAX_PATH] = {};
  GetClassName(hwnd, classNameBuf, MAX_PATH);
  if (lstrcmp(classNameBuf, TEXT("MSCTFIME UI")) != 0 && ...)
  ```